# How to effect click google map?

Tags: javascript, css

In the new google maps, when you click on on the map, it looks like a circle animates from the point you clicked that expands then disappears. When you click on a road, a dot appears, and appears to pulsate every few seconds. How can one accomplish this effect with or without google maps?

In other words, a user can click on a blank space on a page and have the same animated click effect where:

1) Clicking anywhere on HTML page or within a div causes a circle to slowly expand from where the user clicked to be about 5px, then fades out and disappears.

2) Clicking anywhere on HTML page or within a div causes a dot of maybe 3px to appear on the page and (a second circle?) that enlarges from the point of the dot with outline only, that expands for 5px... fades out and disappears... over and over again. (dot remains in place, just the animated circle that continues to "pulsate"

Looking for the best solution can be anywhere from CSS3, Javascript (with or without any libraries) or HTML5.

Comment: Are you asking for someone else to write your code for you? Or do you want suggestions on various approaches? If the latter, you should probably provide some constraints (e.g. required browser support). Your requirements can be met with nothing but CSS3 and Javascript, but only in modern browsers. Legacy support will need a library such as jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting idea. After some fiddling, here are the approaches I made

**1)** Using javascript to append a new element at the clicked location and some CSS animations I came up with [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/apFhx/1/)

The corresponding CSS animation:

```
@keyframes grow {
    0% {
        width: 5px;
        height: 5px;
        margin-top: -2.5px;
        margin-left: -2.5px;
    }
    50% {
        margin-top:-7.5px;
        margin-left: -7.5px;
        width: 15px;
        height: 15px;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        margin-top:-12.5px;
        margin-left: -12.5px;
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

**2)** I couldn't recreate what you mean for this one on Google maps, but from your description I came up with [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/apFhx/5/)

The corresponding CSS animation for that:

```
@keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        width: 5px;
        height: 5px;
        margin-top: -4.5px;
        margin-left: -4.5px;
    }
    100% {
        margin-top:-14.5px;
        margin-left: -14.5px;
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
    }
}
```

These approaches will work on any browsers that support CSS3 animation, the list can be found [*here*](http://caniuse.com/#search=css3%20animation). A fallback similar solution would be to use the same approach but use jQuery's `.animate` or something similar instead

If animations are not supported, the first would simply be a 5px by 5px circle, removed after a second. The second would be a black dot that lasts until the document is clicked again.

Side note: in its current state it won't work in IE I believe because it does not support `document.getElementsByClassName`